# Magento / Mage: How to port from mage to magento v2?

Tags: magento

In magento v1.x, we use:

```
Mage::getVersion()

Mage::app()->getStores()

Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()

Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')
```

What are the equivalents in magento v2?

(And generally, how should we approach porting from mage to magento v2?)

Comment: I wouldn't bother yet if I were you. Magento 2 is still in beta. And they have been promising us a release in December, which is still not there. But for your information, they were talking about migration scripts for our modules to be compatible for v2.
Now for the connection, this way of writing it is already outdated since 1.8 and the new Resource schema, and for the handles of modules, like 'sales/order' I know they are all gone and that we should reference class by their names on v2. Not sur if that help, but maybe if you look at the core module there: https://github.com/magento/magento2

Comment: Agreed.  Don't worry about porting your extensions until Magento 2.0 is released as a stable build.